# Unix/Linux Command to capture a word if other line contain a word (both the lines have common attribute)

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have below data in different lines which will appear in below sequence

```
 trackingID=QsSDsad2yP80Q82G5Y8V2QRWhGQCYy97bX; ***************Some other Data ********************** Trn-status: INCOMPLETE", ***************Some other Data **********************

 trackingID=QsSDsad2yP80Q82G5Y8V2QRWhGQCYy97bX;  ***************Some other Data **********************

 trackingID=QsSDsad2yP80Q82G5Y8V2QRWhGQCYy97bX; ***************Some other Data **********************:{\"details\":[{\"errorCode\":\"MyErrorCode\",\"message\":\"TECHNICAL EXCEPTION\",\"timeStamp\":\"2019-10-03T09:08:56.886Z\"}],***************Some other Data **********************

 trackingID=E32878dfgdf45ddf567u5V2QRsdfdsj657V; ***************Some other Data **********************:{\"details\":[{\"errorCode\":\"Test0001\",\"message\":\"Valiadtion EXCEPTION\",\"timeStamp\":\"2019-10-03T09:08:56.886Z\"}],***************Some other Data **********************
```

These lines are not subsequent lines, there may be other data between these lines.

I want to extract the value of the errorCode attribute if the the value of `message` is `TECHNICAL EXCEPTION` **and** `Trn-status` is `INCOMPLETE` using a Unix/linux command.(want to extract the data for all pairs of matching lines even if there are more than one pair)

Both lines have same trackingID

I'm new to Unix/Linux, Could you please help me to from the command to get the error code?

Comment: In the data you posted there's no line matching your criteria.

Comment: If the data is in JSON format, then please add well-formed JSON to the question so that it's possible to properly test solutions.

Comment: The Data is not in JSOS format. It a data that we generally logging in log files. The common things in these lines they have the same **trackingID**

Comment: Is 'Trn-status' always reported before 'TECHNICAL EXCEPTION' ?

Comment: Yes, 'Trn-status' always reported before 'TECHNICAL EXCEPTION'

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk` for this:

Assuming `Trn-status` always comes before `TECHNICAL EXCEPTION`

```
awk  -F'[\;\=]' '
    { if ( $0 ~ /Trn-status: INCOMPLETE/ ) checkid[$2]=$2 ;
      if ( $2 == checkid[$2] ) {
         if ( $0 ~ /TECHNICAL EXCEPTION/ ) print checkid[$2]
      }
    }' logfile
```

Explanation:

- `-F'[\;\=]'` use either `;` or `=` as field separators; using square brackets allows you to define multiple field separators, semicolon an equal sign are special characters for `awk` so you need to escape them with a backslash
- first line: `$0` represent the whole line, `~` is a (sub)pattern match operator, and `/PATTERN/` the search string. So if we find `Trn-status: INCOMPLETE` in a line, we save the ID (field number two separated by `;` and `=` from other fields) in an array `checkid` where the index is the name of the ID itself (`awk` allows using strings as index counters)
- second line: if we find the ID in another line ...
- third line: check for occurrence of `TECHNICAL EXCEPTION` and print ID if so
- ( `logfile` is your filename )

Comment: Nice solution, I learned something new but OP seems to ask for the ID and the error code pair. On my shell this just means changing separator to `-F'[:;,=]'` (I do like that) and your final `print $2, $6`.

Comment: Good point, overlooked that part. The field will depend on whatever is inbetween, the beginning and the error code, but it goes in the right direction (id output is always similar...). OP is a bit too unspecific there to make a final solution.

Answer (score 0):

This task is too complex for `grep`, but you can use `sed`, for example:

```
sed '/Trn-status:/h;/\\"message\\":\\"TECHNICAL EXCEPTION\\"/!d;G;/Trn-status: INCOMPLETE/!d;s/.*"errorCode\\":\\"//;s/\\".*//' yourfile
```

- `/Trn-status:/h` to always save the last `Trn-status` line in the hold space
- `/\\"message\\":\\"TECHNICAL EXCEPTION\\"/!d` means to `d`elete all lines without (`!`) the given pattern. Note that backslashes need to be escaped with another backslash
- THe rest for the script is only processed for `TECHNICAL EXCEPTION` messages, but now we need to verify that the `Trn-status` is `INCOMPLETE`, so we append the hold space with `G` and `delete` if we don't find `Trn-status: INCOMPLETE`
- now simply remove the part before (`s/.*"errorCode\\":\\"//`) and after (`s/\\".*//`) the Code you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly building on @Fiximan nice lesson in multiple separators for `awk`.

Assuming indeterminate content in the data so iterating across the fields to find the actual error code.

```
awk  -F'[:;,=]' '{
  if ( $0 ~ /Trn-status: INCOMPLETE/ ) checkid[$2]=$2 ;
    if ( $2 == checkid[$2] && $0 ~ /TECHNICAL EXCEPTION/ ) {
      for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ( $i ~ "\"errorCode") print $(i+1), $2
    }
  }
}' logfile | sed "s/[\\\"]//g"
```